# Error session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80, installed chromedriver is 85

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-chromedriver

I'm on a mac trying to run Laravel Dusk, chromedriver is 85.0.4183.87, it gives error  session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80 when running php artisan dusk. Installed Chrome browser is 85.0.4183.102.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the chromedriver was never shutdown so subsequent runs didn't trigger new versions. However terminating the chromedriver in Activitiespanel was not enough but I had to manually delete the drivers in the dusk/bin folder and then run

php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 85 for everything to start working correctly.